# Мониторинг удаления программы C#

Tags: c#, мониторинг, удаление

Я пишу программу деинсталлятор на C #. При удалении выбранной программы я получаю exit code, если он равен 0, то программа удалена, но Opera gx возвращает код выхода 0 сразу после запуска удаления. Подскажите как лучше отследить удаление программы.

Comment: Проверить факт удаления ключа из реестра еще можно, да и даже лучше. Еще наверное можно мониторить занятость инсталлера. Exit коды давно уже никто толком не использует.

Comment: Проблема в том что происходит подчищение ключа реестра после удаления, т.е проблема в том, что operaGx или другая программа имеющая такой косяк моментом почистит реестр и программа будет считаться полностью удаленной. А вот по поводу занятости инсталлера... Можно подробнее об этом?

Comment: Вы можете пока удаляется или устанавливается программа, использующая Windows Installer запустить еще одну установку или удаление? Не можете. Значит где-то в системе это можно проверить, идет ли установка. Но есть инсталлеры приложений, которые не используют винду для установки, с ними этот фокус не прокатит.

Comment: Следите, завершились ли все дочерние процессы деинсталлятора. Посмотрите нет ли процессов с тем-же исполняемым файлом что вы запускали (для случаев, если у программы свой деинсталлятор). Проверьте, папка, в которой находится деинсталлятор, используется ли какими-нибудь процессами (для тех же случаев), разумеется кроме explorer.exe

Answer (score 0):

1. Делаете WMI запрос перед деисталяцией:

   $software  = Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter "Name='XXXXX'"
2. Элемент списка
3. можете потом  вызвать команду $software.uninstall()
4. Делаете повторный WMI запрос.
5. Убеждаемя, что программа не находится.

Надеюсь,что пример, как сделать с помощью c# Вы найдете.Если нет - дайте знать я добавлю код на C#

Comment: Проблема в том, что WMI работает медленее, чем реестр. И ещё WMI содержит не весь список  программ, сверил кол-во программ WMI ~320 программ, реестр ~520

Comment: Буду надеяться, что такая ошибка не распространена в другом ПО, потому что тестировать 520 программ только на одном ПК это уже сложность

Comment: @Isafu- в ресстре помимо приложений еще обновления винды и прочий мелкий мусор, так что разница в количестве - это нормально.

Comment: @aepot проблема в том, что WMI ещё не содержит некоторые программы, а именно программы установленные не с помощью Msi